# why script code removed after $wp_embed->run_shortcode() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
global $wp_embed;
print_r($wp_embed->run_shortcode('[embed]https://twitter.com/minnna_sokuho/status/907222559006920704[/embed]'));
```

this is my code.

I expected result as below,

```
<div class="embed"><blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-width="550"><p lang="ja" dir="ltr">New post (斉藤由貴(51)とかいう不倫しても可愛いから許されるおばさんｗｗｗｗ) has been published on 博士の速報2 - <a href="https://blahblah/HEigtcb8Dz">https://blahblah/HEigtcb8Dz</a> <a href="https://blahblah/zR6hEJfitQ">pic.twitter.com/zR6hEJfitQ</a></p>&mdash; みんなの速報 (@minnna_sokuho) <a href="https://twitter.com/minnna_sokuho/status/907222559006920704">September 11, 2017</a></blockquote><script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script><</div>
```

but,   there was no `<script...></script>` .

I guess that some filter or hooks chages the result, but I've not found what it is.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

that was side effect of other plugin(Autouptimizer)